# Trying to delete a Default, but getting a message that it doesn't exist on the server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, constraints

I need to alter a data type of a column from smallint to bigint (poor design consideration, don't ask). I run the TSQL

```sql
alter table dbo.Test alter column ProductionModeID bigint NULL
```

But get the message:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'DF_Test_ProductionModeID' is dependent on column 'ProductionModeID'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ProductionModeID failed because one or more objects access this column.

I have found `DF_Test_ProductionModeID` in dbo.Test >> Constraints. (I don't know how `DF_Test_ProductionModeID` was created, nor do I believe I need it to exist). I press Delete, choose OK button, and get the following message:

> ===================================
>
> The Default 'DF_Test_ProductionModeID' does not exist on the server. (SqlManagerUI)
>
> ---
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1447.4+((KJ_RTM).100213-0103+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.ObjectDoesNotExist&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DropObjects.DoDropObject(Int32 objectRowIndex)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DropObjects.DropAllObjects(Boolean stopOnError)

So I'm now confused, because if it doesn't exist, then how can it depend on a column?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens when you run the following?

```
ALTER table Test drop DF_Test_ProductionModeID
```

See also [How To Name Default Constraints And How To Drop Default Constraint Without A Name In SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-name-default-constraints-and-how-) for some more info

Comment: Well, that solves the problem, and my original `ALTER` works and my data type is changed. Is there a logical explanation for why I must do this, or is it just "one of those things"? Thanks

Comment: @DanVerdolino other than that the UI is full of little issues like this? Nope. Long ago I resigned myself to learning the DDL and not relying on pointing and clicking around in the UI. As a bonus, the DDL is much easier to store in source control than mouse clicks and menu choices.

Comment: Not sure where you found the constraint in SSMS so can't comment, I usually do everything through scripts because then I know what will get executed instead of SSMS voodoo